# Cannot Retrieve Organization [Organization name]

Tags: iot, thingworx

I'm trying to set visibility permission in my project on Thingworx. But when I select the organization, it says it can't retrieve the organization. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your organization exist in the Thingworx instance and the user you use to access that organization have enough permission on access that organization.